# Colors won't appear in Material Preview?

Tags: materials, color

[image]

I've tried adding materials and changing colors to both the whole model and parts of it but my model remains like this. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it happens with the latest drivers for AMD graphic card, is it what you have? in that case switch to a previous version, or try Render panel > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: The preview window is also black.  It should at least show the checkerboard base.  I agree with @moonboots, it looks like you have a driver problem.

Comment: If it is not a problem with the hardware or something similar, it is also possible that the settings under "Color Management" are set incorrectly. You also get a black image if, for example, the exposure is set incorrectly.